# My iphone is empty and useless after ios update

Tags: iphone

I updated my iphone 4 ios today. But now when i on the iphone it shows an empty screen with IPHONE written in bold, when i unlock it, it shows me a list to select language, when i select it shows me another lis to select country. When i select a country, it takes me to wifi and a button that shows connect to itunes. When i click on connect to itunes, it shows a usb pointing to a music icon. I can't do anything on the iphone apart from this. I don't have a wifi connection and i can't get a pc now. What can i do, please ?

Comment: You will likely need either wifi internet access or access to iTunes to be able to finish the upgrading of iOS. Is it possible for you to get wifi access somehow - like you did when you downloaded the update initially?

Answer (score 1):

The USB pointing to iTunes icon means you need to connect your iPhone to iTunes. *I think* if you don't have a wifi connection and can't get to any PC with iTunes then you will have to wait until you get either one of those. Maybe you can ask a friend to bring a laptop round or go to theirs. Or try and find a wifi without a password nearby somewhere. Also *I think* most McDonald's have free wifi. **Not sure if this will work as I haven't set up a new iOS device since 4S but go back to wifi and click skip. Then try to use your carrier's cellular network to set it up.** Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the next step after connecting the iPhone to a computer running iTunes? The asker still seems to be stuck at this step.

Comment: @patrix The iPhone should show up in iTunes when connected. If it doesn't you can try a different USB port. It may be the case that a USB port is damaged, or the cable is damaged. If it still doesn't show up on iTunes, then you could try a different computer. I doubt it's the iPhone since I am guessing you are still able to charge it.